# Issue não fecha após commit com issue referenciada "Issue #1 fixed"

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Estou fazendo alguns teste do Git Flow e tentei fechar uma Issue #1 através de commit dentro de um branch hotfix, veja no repositório:

https://github.com/chinnonsantos/git-flow/issues/1

Perceba que nas duas tentativas (Resolve issue #1) e (Issue #1 fixed) ao invés de fechar a Issue, ela foi somente referenciada. Houve alguma alteração desse recurso de fechar issue via commit ou eu estou cometendo algum erro no processo?

Pesquisei sobre isso mas só acho postagens sobre como fechar issue através de commit e nada sobre esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é uma função do GitHub. Ele possui uma funcionalidade de fechar issues a partir da mensagem de commit. Até onde eu sei, ele lê a descrição do commit, não aquela mensagem principal. Por exemplo:

```
Adiciona foo ao módulo bar

Closes #123, #456, #789
```

Veja que há uma quebra de linha. E a keyword é `Closes #<número da issue>`.

Leia mais [aqui](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords/).

Comment: Sim, a documentação descreve que em um PR as palavras chaves devem ser informadas na descrição, já em um commit elas podem ser informadas na mensagem. **"... in your pull request description or commit message."**. Hoje eu reli essa pergunta antiga, para sanar essa dúvida novamente kkk, Obrigado.